# How to connect vertices together while joining another vertex in its path?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow, edit-mode, vertices

Hey guys I am wondering how to connect the vertices in blue together while crossing over the path of the one in circled red. How would I connect them all together so the two blue and the red circles all connect as one?

[image: mesh with the vertices to be connected highlited]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option is to use *Join*. Select the two vertices that you want to connect and press <kbd>J</kbd> to connect them. This will automatically create vertices at any edges that the new edge crosses:

[image]

Comment: This would not add a vertice to the center one circled in red though would it? rather just cross over it?

Comment: You can just about see, in the image on the right, that there is a new vertex on that edge. The Join tool creates new vertices on any edge it needs to cross to join the original vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Easy - subdivide the edge (wireframe) of your red circle.  That will place a vertice at it's center.  Click on one of the blue vertices, hold shift down and select the red one.  Both wireframes (edges) should be highlited.

Press F to fill and a new edge line will run from the blue to the red.

Do the same with the other blue and it's done!

If you're new to Blender, you have to select the model in Object mode, then once highlited, get yourself into Edit Mode, press CTL-Tab, select edges, then right click on the blue wire or edge, press W and select 'subdivide'.  To join them, press CLT-Tab again and switch back to vertices.  Do the "Fill".  Repeat this for the other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Edgel3D - I should have noted that I am a beginner at this and that was the reason its maybe an easy answer for you. Thanks again anyway, one more step further to being a Blender Wiz :P

Comment: One flaw - F will create an edge between the two vertices which will sit over the existing face. Use J to also cut through the existing face.

Comment: Yes I should have mentioned that sambler.  I normally delete the old face  & select "faces only", then refill in the new and smaller areas.   DarkXess, I've been toying with Blender for about 2 years and the more I learn the more I realise I don't know!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cut in Edit Mode using <kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: could you please provide a more complete answer. If a user of Blender is really new, it might not be clear how to use the knife tool properly.